# NASM unexpected output when printing

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, keyboard-input

I am new have very small problem with assembly NASM in linux. I made simple program for practice that when you put in the text, it adds simple decoration in form of stars. The expected output is:

```
*********EXAMPLE*********
```

instead:

```
*********EXAMPLE
*********
```

here is the complete code of the program (long) i have use edb to check the code and check EDX register if it match the len take by the null byte check to print correct number of characters.

```
section .data
prompt db "Please enter a word (MAX: 10 Characters) : ", 0xa, 0xd 
plen equ $ - prompt
stars times 9 db "*"


section .bss
text resb 10

section .text
global _start
_start: 


mov eax, 4 
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, prompt 
mov edx, plen   
int 0x80    


mov eax, 3  
mov ebx, 0  
mov ecx, text   
mov edx, 11 
int 0x80    

xor ecx, ecx
mov esi, text    
mov ecx, 0

loop1:      
inc ecx 

cmp byte [esi + ecx], 0x00      

jne loop1   

push ecx        

jmp printexit   

printexit:  


    mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, stars
mov edx, 9
int 0x80


mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, text
pop edx
int 0x80


mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, stars
mov edx, 9 
int 0x80

mov eax, 1 
int 0x80
```

Comment: The input text contains the line feed. You need to trim that yourself. Also you should not search for a zero terminator, instead use the fact that [read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) returns the number of bytes. PS: comment your code especially if you want others to look at it and help.

Comment: AN (un)interesting note is a similar program using MASM would probably break because MASM use `$` to terminate ASCII strings, not `\0`. (If I am parsing things correctly).

Comment: @jww: That's a DOS interrupt service feature, not really related to MASM.